# Wordpress media uploader show media tags and media categories

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I want to change the basic media uploader at backend. When we create a post at backend and click on add media, a popup gets opened showing the "media library" where we have a dropdown having options as shown in the image below.[image]

what i am looking for: I want that this dropdown shall have the media tags and media categories names in dropdown.
i.e I have created a media tag with name "Funny"

so the dropdown shall contain funny as option and on selecting, i shall get the media images that belongs to the media tag "Funny"

Please any help is greately appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

hi i use this site (http://richardsweeney.com/add-a-category-to-media-items-in-wordpress/).
Give the hook how to add the categories. but require some Customization for add slug in the this hook code..